# Maxwell relation for battery undergoing reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, batteries, electrochemistry

I am trying to solve Reif Problem 5.16, and seem to continue to run into a barrier. I here give the problem and solution from the solution manual, as well as my work. This is not a homework question. I am an engineering student self-studying this over the summer.

We begin with the total differential of $E$, where we take as independent variables $\nu, V, T$ and we have used $dT=dV=0$ in the given process.
$$dE = \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \nu} \right)_{V,T}$$
Thus it remains to express the derivative above in terms of known quantities. We can do this by taking $S$ in terms of the chosen independent variables, from which we obtain the expressions (by taking the total differential $dS$, using equation (2) from the problem statement and "dividing" by $dT$ and $d\nu$ at constant "whatever" to get the required partial derivative in the total differential)
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \nu} \right)_{V,T}=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \nu} \right)_{V,T}-zf\Upsilon$$ and
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_{\nu,V}=\frac{\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_{\nu,V}}{T}$$

It is the next step I do not understand. Which Maxwell relation is being used in the solution? I am trying to use the equality of mixed partials in the second equation to substitute away the $S$ derivative, but I don't see where this comes from.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Maxwell relations come from the fact that some quantities are state functions, so you can permute the partial derivatives. In your case, you want to transform $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \nu}\right)_T$ so you want to identify $S$ as the partial derivative of something depending on $\nu,T$ with respect to $T$. The natural candidate is the free energy. Using the differentials:
$$
dE = TdS-zf\Upsilon d\nu\\
dF = -SdT-zf\Upsilon d\nu
$$

(second one because $F$ is a Legendre transform of $E$) you get:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \nu}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial (zf\Upsilon)}{\partial T}\right)_\nu \\
= zf\left(\frac{\partial \Upsilon}{\partial T}\right)_\nu \\
$$
as written in the solution.

Note that I followed your convention, thinking in terms of fixed volume. However, if you look at the problem, it's at fixed pressure, so you should in the above reasoning you need to substitute $E$ by $H$ (enthalpy) and $F$ by $G$ (free enthalpy or Gibb's potential).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you so much! I guess I was thinking that I'd use constant volume since the question says that volume is (to a good approximation) constant.

Comment: Also, if you get the chance, I would be very grateful if you could take a look at the other recent question I asked: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710739/using-quasistatic-processes-to-calculate-quantities/ . Your very lucid answer to this question makes me think you might be able to help me out with that other one too.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that @Chet Miller and all the others address the problem quite well. Your mistake is in thinking $dS=\delta Q/T$ is always true for all quasi-static transformations (ie when writing such differential forms make sense). This is not true, you need the additional assumption that the transformation is reversible. This is why your two approaches are inconsistent, the relaxation of the piston being irreversible, your virtual quasi-static, reversible, adiabatic path cannot reach the final state because it is isentropic.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to qualify the final state and then calculate the entropy difference (since it is a state function) or integrate its differential form along any path. The problem now is to actually calculate the final state, which is complicated due to your adiabatic condition, you can't directly figure it out using state functions since this condition is path dependent. You'll need further assumptions to develop this.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, as I think those answers confused my question about the change in entropy of the gas system as opposed to the change in entropy of the universe. I also don't know why you say $dS=dQ/T$ isn't true for all quasistatic transformations *for a given system* (I agree certain processes may not be quasistatic for all systems involved in the universe, this depends on their respective relaxation times). This fact is derived in Reif.

Comment: Not quite, their answers do not refer to the whole universe. For the formula, it's actually $dS\geq \delta Q/T_e$ with $T_e$ the temperature of the heat bath (from Clausius' inequality), and equality iff the transformation is reversible. For example, recall the case of dithermal engines, this comes from the optimality of a Carnot cycle. I don't know your reference, but this is shown in the Feynman lectures or Fermi's courses.